# JSON array and Android list view not working

Tags: php, android, json, arrays

Ok so i have a php script:

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
  mysql_select_db("FYP");
  $sql=mysql_query("select team_name, games_played, games_won,
  games_drawn, games_lost, goals_for, goals_against, goal_difference, 
  current_points from Team where team_name='Man Utd'");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[]=$row;
  print(json_encode($output));
  mysql_close();
?>
```

that queries my db and returns all the rows matching the query etc etc, then encodes it into JSON, that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "team_name": "Man City",
        "games_played": "24",
        "games_won": "18",
        "games_drawn": "3",
        "games_lost": "3",
        "goals_for": "63",
        "goals_against": "19",
        "goal_difference": "44",
        "current_points": "57"
    },
    {
        "team_name": "Man Utd",
        "games_played": "24",
        "games_won": "17",
        "games_drawn": "4",
        "games_lost": "3",
        "goals_for": "59",
        "goals_against": "24",
        "goal_difference": "35",
        "current_points": "55"
    }
]
```

which to my knowledge, is an array of JSON objects. However when i take this array to display as a list on my app, the tutorial i'm working off requires it to be a JSONObject rather than a JSONArray. I have tried to modify the code to take and array but i have had no luck, can anyone help? The android tut is: http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/

The main part i'm having trouble with is this line of code:

```
    JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");
```

Obviously my JSON doesn't have the element identifier like the sample does, and when i remove that line it doesn't work. Any help would be brilliant, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your JSON result string is legit, it seems that the app (if modeled after the tutorial) is expecting an object as the outer enclosure, something like this:

```
{ "teams":
[
    {
        "team_name": "Man City",
        "games_played": "24",
        "games_won": "18",
        "games_drawn": "3",
        "games_lost": "3",
        "goals_for": "63",
        "goals_against": "19",
        "goal_difference": "44",
        "current_points": "57"
    },
    {
        "team_name": "Man Utd",
        "games_played": "24",
        "games_won": "17",
        "games_drawn": "4",
        "games_lost": "3",
        "goals_for": "59",
        "goals_against": "24",
        "goal_difference": "35",
        "current_points": "55"
    }
]
}
```

This format (of utilizing an object as the outer enclosure) is actually pretty common among web services that return JSON/JSONP.

**Update**
Per [this](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html), the outer has to be an object. Using the recommended structure in my answer, your line would be:

```
JSONArray  teams = json.getJSONArray("teams");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your output by adding one top level:

```
print(json_encode(array('earthquakes' => $output)));
```